# How to initialise/wire beans in Grails Spock unit tests?

Tags: spring, grails, spring-data, spock

I'm wanting to test a Grails controller that contains a bean (I'll move it to a Service when I get it working, but I just want to keep it simple now).

```
//resources.groovy
beans {
    myBean(com.me.MyBean) 
}


// MyBean.java
// this needs to be in java as it is playing with spring-data-neo4j
package com.me;
public class MyBean {
    String show() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

// TestController.groovy
package com.me

import com.me.MyBean

class TestController {

    def myBean

    def index() {
        render myBean.show()
    }
}


// TestControllerSpec.groovy
package com.me

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

import com.me.*

@TestFor(TestController)
class TestControllerSpec extends Specification {

    def myBean

    def setup() {
        defineBeans {
            myBean(com.me.MyBean) {bean->
                bean.autowire = true
            }
        }
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    def "show() returns Hello"() {
        when:
        def rc = controller.myBean.show()
        def rc2 = myBean.show()

        then:
        rc == "Hello"
        rc2 == "Hello"
    }
}
```

Within TestControllerSpec, myBean is null.  controller.myBean is also null.  I think this is because Spring is not picking the bean up and wiring it in.  I gather that in unit tests not all spring beans are available, but what do I need to do to get controller.myBean to be instantiated and wired up correctly?

Comment: You may not want to do that in unit tests. You could mock or stub it instead in the `setup` method: `def setup() { controller.myBean = Stub(MyBean) }` and then use [interactions](http://spock-framework.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interaction_based_testing.html) to test your controller.

Comment: Agreed, but what show() is actually doing in my real code is writing to a graph database that is held in memory.  I want to check that my method actually does result in real data being written to the db, not that my method calls a method that writes to the db (i.e. by mocking).  (And, of course, in the process, to get a better understanding of how Spring actually works).

Comment: But wouldn't it be better to write a unit test for MyBean and perform that test there? Otherwise an integration or a functional step may make more sense in this case..

Comment: Yes - thanks, your answer has caused me to discover the difference between integration and functional testing in Grails.  I haven't managed to find an example of where a bean is written within src/java and is unit tested within Grails, so I'll post a separate question on SO about this.

Answer (score 5):

You must be mocking the  myBean as below

```
def myBean = Mock(MyBean)
```

or

```
MyBean myBean = Mock()
```

and then stub out method for your need if required as below:

```
myBean.show >> "test data"
```

and then assign it to controller object which is already mocked for you.

```
controller.myBean = myBean
```

and there you go.

Or optionally you can stub out myBean and give stubbed implementations. For example,

```
MyBean myBean = Stub(){
show() >> {return "sample text"}
}
controller.myBean = myBean
```

The reason for doing this is we are not testing the integration of application entities like controller, views or domain but we are testing a single unit i.e. a method and hence we should be just testing  it and for integration we should be using integration test cases which would be similar in everything except you won't require any mocking in normal scenarios.

**Edit:**

found another useful feature to mock services or beans using `defineBeans` closure as below:

```
        defineBeans {
            adapter(Adapter)
            helperService(HelperService)
        }
```

This will allow beans to be accessed from `grailsApplication`.

Hope it helps.