# How do you test a spring bean within Grails?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, spock

This is a follow-on question to that posted here:

[How to initialise/wire beans in Grails Spock unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26994716/how-to-initialise-wire-beans-in-grails-spock-unit-tests?noredirect=1#comment42520385_26994716)

I haven't managed to find an example of where a spring bean is written in java within src/java and which is then unit tested within Grails using Spock.

Given:

```
// MyBean.java
// this needs to be in java as it is playing with spring-data-neo4j
package com.me;
public class MyBean {
    @Autowired
    def someNeo4jBeanThatCannotBeTestedByItself


    String readFromDb() {
        // this will execute code to actually read from a DB
        return "Hello from DB";
    }
}
```

Note that "someNeo4jBeanThatCannotBeTestedByItself" is a bean that is associated with spring-data-neo4j and I want to see that my code actually writes stuff here, so I want my unit/integration test to load spring beans (I don't want to mock this out).

What does the test case look like, is it an Integration test?  I've tried a couple of variations, but can't get the spring beans to be initialised by Grails test-app.

Comment: If it's an integration test, the bean is autowired. If not than you should you a mock using this: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#Test%20Mixin%20Basics

Specifically, mockFOr and demand. 

here's a real example: http://pastebin.com/QC106Nuj

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old post. As this is not answered yet, i'm trying to answer. If you figured out already, you can ignore.

I believe for this you can write Unit Test. But if this class is under, src/groovy or src/java spring autowire doesn't work. You need to add bean,`someNeo4jBeanThatCannotBeTestedByItself` and `MyBean`, in `resources.groovy' file as shown below:

```
beans={
      someNeo4jBean (Neo4jBeanClass)
      myBean(MyBean){
      someNeo4jBeanThatCannotBeTestedByItself = ref(someNeo4jBean)   
      }
}
```

You can remove `@Autowired` annotation in your bean,`MyBean`

Now for spec to work , you need to add this property to your spec, `static loadExternalBeans = true`, then it loads beans present in `resources.groovy` file.

Sample Spec:

```
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
class MyBeanSpec extends Specification {
    static loadExternalBeans =true//this loads beans present in resources.groovy
    def myBean

     def setup() {
        myBean= applicationContext.getBean("myBean")
        //now you can use this `myBean` in test cases..
    }

}
```

I also had similar situation and i got rid of with this approach.
Hope this helps.

Comment: `static loadExternalBeans =true` was helpful